# Xcode 4.2 MultiView App

Tags: ios, xcode

i am a fairly new iOS programmer, and I've lately been having trouble with my multi view app. Im using a paged based application with two view. I just don't seem to be able to make an IBAction that allows me to switch between each view. i tried using:

```
[self presentModalViewController: SecondViewController animated: YES];
```

but i keep getting an error that says:

> "use of undeclared identifier 'SecondViewController'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use of undeclared xxx
```

So you should declare that FIRST.

Please follow these steps:

1. Create new file named SecondViewController and xib
2. In your first view controller, add the code to the head of the FirstViewController.m file to import the second view controller:

   #import "SecondViewController.h"
3. When you present the second view controller, you should initialize it first, you should write:

   SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
4. Now you can invoke your code but with the instance:

   [self presentModalViewController: secondVC animated: YES];
5. Do not forget cleaning up:

   [secondVC release];

Hope to help:)

Comment: +1, It isn't related to the question, but releasing the secondVC could be mentioned here too.  (there is a leak if this is the only code run)